# Rails4 Deploy ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, capistrano

My deployment is running fine until the migration ..     which fails

```
    rake aborted!
    DEBUG [874287b0]    ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
    DEBUG [874287b0]    /home/kadoudal/rails/swim-tech.eu/site/swimtech/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:52:in `resolve_hash_connection'
```

I run :  cap staging deploy:check:linked_files, whic is successful , database.yml is symlinked correctly and contains :

```
# encoding: utf-8

 defaults: &defaults
     adapter: mysql2
    host: localhost
    timeout: 60000
    encoding: utf8


production:
     <<: *defaults
    database: mydb_production
    username: xxxxxxxxxxx
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

why the Adapter is not found ?

Answer (score 3):

forgot I was running a cap staging.... and there is no staging db in the database.yml

Answer (score 0):

I created a staging server by cloning the production server on Rackspace. In this scenario, I want the staging server to still use the 'production' rails environment and the production db (on the staging server), so I set this in the config/deploy/staging.rb file:

```
set :stage, :production
```

and it works great.